# Flutter GridView's children are changing their size, but fixed size is preferred

Tags: flutter, web, responsive-design

I am looking for responsive design solutions in Flutter for Web.
I am looking for solutions to make the web app responsive. However, I want the Flutter's GridView elements (specifically the Card widgets) **not to change their size**, but to be the same size all the time. (Changing the size of the Card widget causes errors in the display of the elements contained in that card).
I have used GridView together with the "extent" and "builder" methods in both cases, unfortunately the cards change their size, so that not all the elements contained in them are displayed correctly.
Another issue, I would like the widgets **to form an rectangle**, so if there are, for example, 12 cards, I want them to form a 6x2 or 4x3 or 3x4 (columns x rows) matrix, not, for example, 7+5 - which is undesirable.
The extra columns should only form when the browser window allows it, i.e. when it accommodates the extra columns (as I wrote at the beginning, this must be done without changing the size of the cards). Cards in view should be always centered.
I hope I have described the problem in detail and clearly, if not I can add graphics to better illustrate the problem.

Here is code Example (minimum working code) utilising GridView (with builder option):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(context) =>
    MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage()
    );
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> elements = ["Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "A Million Billion Trillion", "A much, much longer text that will still fit"];


  @override
  Widget build(context) =>
    Scaffold(
      body: GridView.builder(
        itemCount: elements.length,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
          maxCrossAxisExtent: 130.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 20.0,
          mainAxisSpacing: 20.0,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (context, i) => Card(
          child: Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0), child: Text(elements[i])
            )
          )
        )
      )
   );
}
```

Code above don't use custom cards, I did not want to put them here, as they use images from local hard drive, which makes the code inoperable without making some extra changes. But if You need it I can put here the whole code.

**Important thing:** I will always have 6, 8, 10 or 12 images (didn't decided yet) on this page! Always same images count on first page.

Below image show desired cards placement, for 6 and 8 cards respectively:

[image]

Below I added **undesired placement** of 10 Cards widgets in Grid View. I **don't** want such form (4+4+2). It must be 5x2 or 2x5, to form rectangle.

[image]

Comment: Can you include an image that you are trying to get

Comment: OK, I will upload images that show preffered problem solution

Comment: can you try with `childAspectRatio`

Comment: I will test it. Did not used it so far.

Comment: GridView uses `childAspectRatio` to size the children.